# Parsing 2D delimited string into a range

Tags: excel, vba, string, parsing

I have a two dimensional string delimited by line and within each line delimited by value.

So it's a comma delimited string with an EOL marker at the end of each line. Example:

```
val1, val2, val3 ... valn [EOL]
val1, val2, val3 ... valn [EOL]
...
val1, val2, val3 ... valn [EOL]
```

If I create a loop to split() each line by [EOL] then another loop inside that to split() each value by ',' and then write each value one at a time to a cell in the worksheet it takes forever so I'm looking for a more efficient solution.

Is it possible to parse the string into a 2D array/variant and then write the whole thing at once to a named range?

Comment: Multiple cells in a range is technically a 2D array also so you can use `UBound()` and `Resize()` to enter the array into a range directly without looping.

Answer (score 2):

We can do what @Macro Man said in the comments. It will be easy if all rows contain the same count of comma delimited values. If not, it will be more complicated. But nevertheless solvable.

```
Option Base 0

Sub test()

 sString = "val1, val2, val3 ... valn" & Chr(10) & "val1, val2 ... valn" & Chr(10) & "val1, val2, val3, val4 ... valn" & Chr(10) & "val1" & Chr(10)

 Dim aDataArray() As Variant
 Dim lLinesCount As Long
 Dim lValuesCount As Long
 Dim lMaxValuesCount As Long

 aLines = Split(sString, Chr(10))
 lLinesCount = UBound(aLines)
 ReDim aDataArray(0 To lLinesCount, 0)

 For i = LBound(aLines) To UBound(aLines)
  aValues = Split(aLines(i), ",")
  lValuesCount = UBound(aValues)
  If lValuesCount > lMaxValuesCount Then lMaxValuesCount = lValuesCount
  ReDim Preserve aDataArray(0 To lLinesCount, 0 To lMaxValuesCount)

  For j = LBound(aValues) To UBound(aValues)
   aDataArray(i, j) = aValues(j)
  Next
 Next

 With ActiveSheet
  .Range("B2").Resize(lLinesCount + 1, lMaxValuesCount + 1).Value = aDataArray
 End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to first assemble an array in memory and then transfer it in one line of code. The first function, `MultiSplit`, assumes that each row contains the same number of elements. The second function, `MultiSplit2`, drops that assumption (at the cost of more processing). Use whichever version matches your situation.

```
Function MultiSplit(s As String, d1 As String, d2 As String) As Variant
    'd1 is column delimiter, d2 is row delimiter
    'returns an array

    Dim m As Long, n As Long, i As Long, j As Long
    Dim tempRows As Variant, tempRow As Variant
    Dim retA As Variant 'return array

    tempRows = Split(s, d2)
    m = UBound(tempRows)
    If Len(tempRows(m)) = 0 Then 'original string ends with a delimiter
        m = m - 1
        ReDim Preserve tempRows(m)
    End If

    tempRow = Split(tempRows(0), d1)
    n = UBound(tempRow)
    ReDim retA(1 To m + 1, 1 To n + 1) '1-based more natural for intended ranges

    For i = 1 To m + 1
        For j = 1 To n + 1
            retA(i, j) = tempRow(j - 1)
        Next j
        If i < m + 1 Then tempRow = Split(tempRows(i - 1), d1) ' next row to process
    Next i
    MultiSplit = retA
End Function

Sub test()
    Dim testString As String, A As Variant, R As Range
    testString = "a,b,c,d;e,f,g,h;i,j,k,l"

    A = MultiSplit(testString, ",", ";")
    Set R = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(UBound(A, 1), UBound(A, 2)))
    R.Value = A
End Sub
```

Here is a version that can handle rows of various lengths:

```
Function MultiSplit2(s As String, d1 As String, d2 As String) As Variant
    'd1 is column delimiter, d2 is row delimiter
    'returns an array

    Dim m As Long, n As Long, i As Long, j As Long
    Dim tempRows As Variant, jaggedArray As Variant
    Dim retA As Variant 'return array

    tempRows = Split(s, d2)
    m = UBound(tempRows)
    If Len(tempRows(m)) = 0 Then 'original string ends with a delimiter
        m = m - 1
        ReDim Preserve tempRows(m)
    End If

    ReDim jaggedArray(0 To m)
    For i = 0 To m
        jaggedArray(i) = Split(tempRows(i), d1)
        If UBound(jaggedArray(i)) > n Then n = UBound(jaggedArray(i))
    Next i

    ReDim retA(1 To m + 1, 1 To n + 1) '1-based more natural for intended ranges

    For i = 1 To m + 1
        For j = 1 To 1 + UBound(jaggedArray(i - 1))
            retA(i, j) = jaggedArray(i - 1)(j - 1)
        Next j
    Next i
    MultiSplit2 = retA
End Function

Sub test2()
    Dim testString As String, A As Variant, R As Range
    testString = "a,b,c;d,e,f,g,h;i;j,k,l,m,n,o,p;"

    A = MultiSplit2(testString, ",", ";")
    Set R = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(UBound(A, 1), UBound(A, 2)))
    R.Value = A
End Sub
```

To get some timing information, I wrote a sub to generate a string which splits into 1000 rows and up to 100 columns:

```
Sub test3()
    Dim s As String, A As Variant, R As Range
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, start As Double
    Dim n As Long

    For i = 1 To 1000
        n = i Mod 100
        For j = 1 To n
            s = s & "a" & IIf(j < n, ",", vbCrLf)
        Next j
        DoEvents 'in case it hangs
    Next i
    Debug.Print "String has length " & Len(s)
    start = Timer
    A = MultiSplit2(s, ",", vbCrLf)
    Set R = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(UBound(A, 1), UBound(A, 2)))
    R.Value = A
    Debug.Print "Finished in " & Timer - start & " seconds"
End Sub
```

When I ran it I got the output:

```
String has length 99990
Finished in 0.09375 seconds
```